# PHP - non-dynamic statement

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have a php statement:

`$latest_pollsid` that contains a number which increases by 1 every time a specific form is submitted. I am reading this statement into several functions and for one of these functions I would like it to capture the value at the current time and not update. Essentially I want it to read the statement when the function runs, grab the number, and then display that without it changing in the future even when the value of the statement itself changes. Is there a way to do this with PHP?

Any help is much appreciated.

UPDATE - PHP FUNCTION CODE:

```
function polls_latest_id() {
    global $wpdb;
    $poll_id = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT pollq_id FROM $wpdb->pollsq WHERE pollq_active = 1 ORDER BY pollq_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1");
    return intval($poll_id);
}
```

MANAGE POLLS CODE
This page manages to list all of the polls with the correct id's but without knowing PHP very well I am struggling to interpret this:

```
                        echo "<tr id=\"poll-$poll_id\" $style>\n";
                        echo '<td><strong>'.number_format_i18n($poll_id).'</strong></td>'."\n";
                        echo '<td>';
                        if($current_poll > 0) {
                            if($current_poll == $poll_id) {
                                echo '<strong>'.__('Displayed:', 'wp-polls').'</strong> ';
                            }
                        } elseif($current_poll == 0) {
                            if($poll_id == $latest_poll) {
                                echo '<strong>'.__('Displayed:', 'wp-polls').'</strong> ';
                            }
                        } else if(in_array($poll_id, $multiple_polls)) {
                                echo '<strong>'.__('Displayed:', 'wp-polls').'</strong> ';
                        }
```

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: Sounds like something you would normally use a db for. Are you using one?

Comment: @AdRock I have no idea about how to go about it, but I have edited post with the code for the php function that increases the value by one.

Comment: That function does not increase anything by one, all it does is read the current value from the database. So display what is returned by that funbction

Comment: Are trying to capture the ID just created or trying to capture the most recent ID?  You could use a cookie or have a hidden field tracking the poll ID depending on what is appropriate -- but this doesn't deal with a more permanent ability for the user to choose which previous poll to review and work with. Perhaps describe the purpose (not just what you want to occur) and it may be easier to offer suggestions.

Comment: @MaxHaaksman I have a form that lets users create a poll and when they click submit, a post is created in the background which should simply contain the short code for embedding the poll they just created.

Comment: @AdRock could I create a variable that pulls the number from the $ statement and then load that?

Comment: This is probably the best place for this question seeing as it's Wordpress related http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AdRock Ok thanks I will post it there.